# one switch works two don't- 35m cable

Tags: router, ethernet, cable, hub

I am connecting my main ISP router to another router via a 35m ethernet cable, however, I have a connectivity problem, a bit long to explain so bear with me:

If I connect the cable between the ISP router at one end and a  switch (
TP-Link LS1005G) on the other end, I lose the connection after a few days.

If I connect the ethernet cable to the same switch (
TP-Link LS1005G) near the ISP router and then the other end to an access point (TP-Link TL-WA1201), it works permanently.

Given the access point has only one port, I need to connect another switch before it. I have already tried two varieties of switches, the TP-Link TL-SG1005D and MERCUSYS 5-Port 10/100/1000Mbps Desktop Ethernet Switch, but I do not get the connectivity with either of these.

I am at a loss and would appreciate suggestion what hub could help deliver the connectivity.

Comment: Which "connection" do you lose -- do wired devices stop being able to reach the Internet? or the ISP router? or the AP? Do the link-status LEDs on the switch say there's no link for the ISProuter--switch connection, or the switch--AP one? What kind of Ethernet cable do you have, did you make it yourself or was it pre-made?

Comment: 35m is well within Ethernet limits. Try putting new ends on the cable, or, try a good (top) quality manufactured Ethernet cable.

Comment: It may seem unlikely, but make sure you do not have a hub with separate uplink ports from regular ports.

Comment: User1686, thanks for your comments. So, the lights on the hubs when connected by this ethernet cable do not light. In fact, they flicker very weirdly and do not stay on as normal. I made this cable myself, but as mentioned it seems to work fine if I have the good hub on one end and the AP on the other end. I even tried an Netgear R8000 instead of the AP and it stays on.

Comment: Problem resolved. Needed to use a cross over cable between the two hubs.